# Where to find a list of Serilog Web.Config and App.Config settings

Tags: serilog

I am struggling a bit to find a complete list of possible settings to Serilog using C# Web App. I would like examples of all settings possible to set in Web.Config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each sink will have its own set of settings. There is no common source for sink configuration to my knowledge. For a curated list of sinks, please see https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Provided-Sinks